# R Shiny conditional panel never shows up, even when condition is met

Tags: r, shiny

If the user selects not to keep only nouns and adjectives (`"pos"` selectInput set to `FALSE`), then they should be prompted with whether stopwords should be removed (`"stop"` selectInput).

However, despite me being careful to write the condition in JS and not R, the conditional panel never shows up, even when the condition is met. I am stumped.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
shinyApp(

ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(

fluidRow(
column (2,
wellPanel(
h5("Parameters"),
tabsetPanel(
tabPanel("Text",
selectInput("pos", label = h5("Keep only nouns & adjectives?"), choices = list("Yes" = TRUE, "No" = FALSE), selected = TRUE),
conditionalPanel(
condition = "input.pos == false",
selectInput("stop", label = h5("Remove stopwords?"), choices = list("Yes" = TRUE, "No" = FALSE), selected = TRUE)
)))))))),

server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {

})

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition needed quotes and upper case...

```
shinyApp(

  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(

    fluidRow(
      column (2,
              wellPanel(
                h5("Parameters"),
                tabsetPanel(
                  tabPanel("Text",
                           selectInput("pos", label = h5("Keep only nouns & adjectives?"), choices = list("Yes" = TRUE, "No" = FALSE), selected = TRUE),
                           conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.pos == 'FALSE'",
                             selectInput("stop", label = h5("Remove stopwords?"), choices = list("Yes" = TRUE, "No" = FALSE), selected = TRUE)
                           )))))))),

  server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  })

)
```

Comment: god bless you cory